# MySQL select query from joined table having exact number of child rows

Tags: mysql, doctrine

I have two tables as below.

**PermissionAccessEntities**

---

```
peID      |   petID
-------------------
1         |   1
2         |   4
3         |   1
4         |   2
5         |   4
6         |   4
-------------------
```

**PermissionAccessEntityGroups**

---

```
pegID     |   peID     |  gID
-----------------------------
1         |   5        |  1
2         |   5        |  2
3         |   5        |  3
4         |   6        |  2
5         |   6        |  3
-----------------------------
```

Now I've a `getOne` doctrine query as below-

```
select pae.peID from PermissionAccessEntities pae 
left join PermissionAccessEntityGroups paeg1 on pae.peID = paeg1.peID 
left join PermissionAccessEntityGroups paeg2 on pae.peID = paeg2.peID 
where petID = 4 and paeg1.gID = 2 and paeg2.gID = 3;
```

Which returns `5` & `6`. But I want to get the result which has exact number of matching rows. In this case which is `6`.

Is there any way to use JOIN to fetch the same resultset as above ?.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your query doesn't return any results for the sample data you have supplied...

Comment: Sorry, the table data was wrong. Fixed it.

Comment: What do you mean by "exact number of matching rows"? I can't see any difference in the results for `peID=5` and `peID=6`.

Comment: @Nick there is one extra row of `gID = 1` for `peID = 5`. It seems that OP wants to consider only those `peID` value(s) which has `gID = 2 and 3 only`

Comment: So, `peID=5` has 3 `gID=(1,2,3)` & `peID=6` has 2 `gID=(2,3)`. I want to get only `peID=6`, not `peID=5`.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya you're right.

Comment: @CoderBoy check the updated posted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Where` condition will not help you in this case. Because, you want to consider count of all the rows for further filtering. You will need to use `Group By` with conditional filtering using `Having` clause.
- We can also simplify query to use only one join with the `PermissionAccessEntityGroups` table.
- [`Count()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) function is used to count the number of rows in a group. We can also use `Sum( conditional statements )` to count number of rows matching a condition. Conditional statement will return 1 for matching rows, and 0 for non-matching rows.

Try the following query instead:

```
SELECT pae.peID 
FROM PermissionAccessEntities AS pae 
LEFT JOIN PermissionAccessEntityGroups AS paeg 
  ON pae.peID = paeg.peID 
WHERE pae.petID = 4
GROUP BY pae.peID
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(paeg.gID IN (2,3))
```

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hzCEgrR6thaZFQXEbHEfCZ/0)

---

Now, remember that `Count(NULL) = 0`; however `COUNT(0) = COUNT(1) = 1`. So, another way of writing this query using `Count()` function only is:

```
SELECT pae.peID 
FROM PermissionAccessEntities AS pae 
LEFT JOIN PermissionAccessEntityGroups AS paeg 
  ON pae.peID = paeg.peID 
WHERE pae.petID = 4
GROUP BY pae.peID
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN paeg.gID IN (2,3) THEN 1 END)
```

### [DB Fiddle DEMO 2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hzCEgrR6thaZFQXEbHEfCZ/1)

Comment: Returns exactly the same result as OPs original query

Comment: @Nick no it would not. Do u have fiddle ? OP changed the data afterwards

Comment: Yup I have a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=74c5b6100d8e78737679c54af7601390) and with OPs new data your query gives exactly the same result as OPs original query. Hence my second comment to the question.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya & Nick Yes, the updated one works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your desired result by first looking for entries which match (2,3) and then seeing if any of those also match one of the other values. Any which doesn't (`paeg2.peID IS NULL`) is an exact match:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(pae.peID)
FROM PermissionAccessEntities pae 
JOIN PermissionAccessEntityGroups paeg1 ON paeg1.peID = pae.peID AND paeg1.gID IN (2,3)
LEFT JOIN PermissionAccessEntityGroups paeg2 ON paeg2.peID = pae.peID AND paeg2.gID NOT IN (2,3)
WHERE pae.petID = 4 AND paeg2.peID IS NULL
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00dfc966a8f0fc7e795175c5e460a3e4)

Comment: another approach . I think u need to put `where pae.petID = 4` also. +1

Comment: @Nick Thought it works fine, I'm wondering how will it work for more than two rows?
For example, I've `gID=1,2,3,4` & want to search for `gID=1,2,3`. Do we need another join then?

Comment: @CoderBoy just change the `IN` conditions to `IN (1,2,3)` and `NOT IN (1,2,3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pae.peID FROM PermissionAccessEntities pae 
INNER JOIN PermissionAccessEntityGroups paeg1 ON  pae.peID=paeg1.peID
WHERE pae.petID = 4 AND paeg1.peID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT peID FROM 
PermissionAccessEntityGroups WHERE gID NOT IN (2,3));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It returns `6` but two entries.